# Is device BIOS stored on device controller?

Tags: bios, computer-architecture

I am reading this article, [How does system bootstrap](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/feng/cos/resources/BIOS/), according to it:

> The BIOS then looks for other devices' ROMs to see if any of them have BIOSes. Normally, the IDE/ATA hard disk BIOS will be found at C8000h and executed. If any other device BIOSes are found, they are executed as well.

I know that the so called main BIOS is stored on BIOS chip, but where are the device BIOSs, are they stored on device controllers ?
And how does main BIOS detect device BIOSs ?

Answer (score 1):

Most "device" BIOSes (for the stuff on the motherboard itself, like the IDE or SATA controller) are integrated in the motherboard BIOS firmware by the manufacturer of the motherboard.
Technically they are separate things, but you can't individually update/replace them.

Plug-in cards that need a bios (video-cards, SCSI controllers, some network cards (with "boot from network" capability) and FibreChannel host-adapters are the most common examples) have their own on the card itself. These days almost always integrated in the controller chip, but in the past (boot-roms on network and SCSI cards) they were sometimes separate EPROMS. In some cases you even could buy a card without the EPROM (in which case it wouldn't be a bootable device) and could buy the EPROM and upgrade later.
This was a thing when the first PCIe NVMe upgrade cards for PC's without SSD started to appear on the market a few years ago. There were a lot of cheap cards around that didn't have a BIOS. Those weren't bootable, so you could only use your brand-spanking new fast NVMe SSD as data-disk and not as system drive.

With more modern UEFI systems (UEFI is NOT the same as a BIOS even though many people call it a BIOS) it is also possible that the card doesn't have a bios/firmware chip, but instead the code is loaded from a file in the EFI partition, by the computers UEFI firmware.
(Rare though. Never seen that myself.)

Comment: I don't think the part about nvme is true. The reason that you can't boot one with "a cheap upgrade card" is not because of the upgrade card but the UEFI itself lacking NVMe DXE driver (which is not an equivalent to "additonal BIOS" AFAIK) and more, and I'm not sure what's a "non-cheap" upgrade card unless you are talking about some kind of RAID one. And DXE driver can indeed be transiently loaded from the ESP, which can e.g. make the NVMe drive (its ESP) "available" to the UEFI and hence to e.g. grub.

Comment: @TomYan You are right, but I didn't want to overcomplicate my answer. But non-RAID PCIe cards with 1 or 2 M.2 slots for NVMe SSD's with a boot-bios (for non-EUFI systems) are a thing. I have several of those at the office. In UEFI you would have the driver in the on-board UEFI firmware or can load it on demand from the EFI partition (if that resides on an embedded flash-medium or on a different drive, obviously).

Comment: Hmm interesting. Indeed I distanced myself from BIOS way before I started using my first NVMe drive.